# Why should I use AsyncCallback?

Tags: c#

I've been using the `Action` as a callback for my *async* method, and I just stumbled upon `AsyncCallback`.

I am wondering whether should I change the `Action` to `AsyncCallback`? Would there be any difference?

Comment: Don't use callbacks in the first place.  Return a `Task`.

Comment: is your Action an Action<IAsyncResult>?  If so it's a AsyncCallback already...

Comment: From a quick look into MSDN, AsyncCallback and Action are not related, meaning that AsyncCallback can be used in Windows forms application for example, please see code example on this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.asynccallback(v=vs.110).aspx. Latest version of .NET there is 4.0, suggesting the class is old.

Comment: @Servy I can't believe I spend so much time trying to make this work with callbacks because I couldn't understand why it returns before it completes when I use await :D.. I feel so dumb. But thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AsyncCallback` is an old delegate that is used when following the Begin / End async pattern with `IAsyncResult`.

Unless you are using `IAsyncResult` in your async code, then I wouldn't bother with it.

If you are using something that uses Begin / End, I would suggest using [`TaskFactory.FromAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.fromasync(v=vs.110).aspx) and converting it to an awaitable task.